# How to save (store) PDF file generated by weasyprint to specified directory?

Tags: python, django, weasyprint

I need my **pdf** files that is generated by **weasyprint** to be some specified folder, for example in the folder "**my_project/pdf_files/**"

NOTE: I am using django framework for my project. And here is the structure of project.

```
my_project/

----pdf_generator_app/

--------admin.py

--------models.py

--------views.py

pdf_files/
```

Currently I have this in my **views.py**

```
def generate(student_id):
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, application_id=student_id)
    html = render_to_string('contract.html', {'student': student})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="some_file.pdf"'
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf('myfile.pdf', 
                                           presentational_hints=True,
                                           stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/css/styles.css')])
    return response
```

But this view does not store pdf file to a directory. It simply show file on browser. I need the file to be stored in the directory **my_project/pdf_files/**

Comment: It will be downloaded directly if I replace **`response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="some_file.pdf"'`** with **`response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some_file.pdf"'`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oppsite to me, I got the PDF file but couldn't view it on my browser. 
Replace 'myfile.pdf' to an absolulte path and check if if generates the pdf file. It work for me in my condition.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the out put to the binary mode and it worked.

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)


def hello_pdf():
    # Make a PDF straight from HTML in a string.
    html = render_template('template-1.html', name=name)

    pdf = HTML(string=html).write_pdf()

    if os.path.exists(dirname):

        f = open(os.path.join(dirname, 'mypdf.pdf'), 'wb')
        f.write(pdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a file name as a parameter and it will store the PDF as a file:

```
HTML(string=html).write_pdf('out.pdf')
```